# Fit image with height 100% in flex

Tags: html, image, css, flexbox

I have a responsive background image in a div. And i want a two column flex layout on top of it, in which the left layout have image of height 100% of the parent div with width auto scale like responsive image. and the right part is a two line text centering in the flex.

This is the closest i can get so far. But the flex does not stretch to fit the background div image and the left image does not scale accordingly when browser resize.

**Note: None of the width and height in px should be specified in the code**

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.left {
  height: 100%;
}

.right {
  flex: 1;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
  <div style="position: relative;">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTkyfCkzwQ7Lx4v3YRNao0lQgM-VkEj6iLWTHE8KqHF5tk4cl15WQ" style="width: 100%">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;">
      <div class="parent">
        <div class="left">
          <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRsxhzGxiYQU_vp2YlN1LTMxQsYMhFDqTZLwfqMylCwqIahCu00Mf_0aDQ">
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <p>
            123
          </p>
          <p>
            456
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Expectation: 
[image]

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/tgrs0uo4/1/

Comment: @Michael_B quite near but unfortunately no. I have created a [jsfiddle] (https://jsfiddle.net/tgrs0uo4/4/) with square image in left column for illustration. as you can see the square image does not maintain the aspect ratio of the image (1:1) inside the flex box

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/tgrs0uo4/5/

Comment: @Michael_B much closer but still there is something missing. The image do not take up the height of the background image div. Ideally the image height should be the same as the background image div height while maintaining the image own ratio

Comment: Just remove `align-items: center` from the `.left` container: https://jsfiddle.net/tgrs0uo4/6/

Comment: @Michael_B hmm... seems very close to me but upon chrome inspection the original image is a perfect square but the scale image is not. Is there any reason for the misscaling?

Comment: Switch from `flex: 1` to `flex: auto`: https://jsfiddle.net/tgrs0uo4/7/

Comment: @Michael_B the image deviates from its own aspect ratio more after changing from `flex: 1` to `flex: auto` during browser resize

Comment: Okay, buddy. I hope I got you a bit closer. Need to focus on other work now. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Remove 
`align-items: center;`
from the `parent` div.

If you want to center align the text elements, use `padding` or `position: relative/position: absolute`

Then apply
`height: 100%;` to the image.

Comment: I have updated the code in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/waa90yhy/1/). I don't see the left image scale according to ratio when browser resize. And that the flex (or left image) height does not take up 100% height of background image.

Answer (score 0):

add `align-self: normal` to the image